# Send a message from an iframe on the main page

Tags: javascript, iframe, message, addeventlistener, postmessage

I have seen from this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage , the way to pass a data correctly to an iframe. But now I want to send an answer:

```
//from main page
myIframe.contentWindow.postMessage('send me a response', '*');
//from iframe of main page
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
    function receiveMessage(event){
          alert(event.data);//the value of message
          //now i need to send an answer 'this is a response'
    }
}
```

How do I send an answer to the main page from the iframe?
I need really of this answer.

Edit:

Ok i found the solution ty at all.

Answer (score 7):

You have access to the parent window on the global `window.parent`.

I believe it is as easy as using this object's method at this point to postMessage. So something like:

```
var parent = window.parent;
parent.postMessage("some message");
```

A full example can be found [here](https://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe).

The gist is the window.parent.postMessage() function takes the following arguments: `otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);`

Comment: I understand you advise me to use the same message in reverse, but look at my answer, it's 'undefined': but apparently it works

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using **easyXDM**

[EasyXDM WebSite](http://easyxdm.net/wp/)

Comment: I would prefer a method that does not use sockets, But if I had another need it would be a good solution, but in my case I can not use this solution.

Comment: I understand. So if the page and the iFrame are on the same domain, Maxwell's answer should do the trick!

Comment: I made this 
https://github.com/TheInvoker/Duplex-Sandboxed-Iframe-Listener